# Apache not sending any request header

Tags: java, docker, apache, header

I got this issue by implementing the Apache OIDC module, but it's not just the module headers that are not being sent but any header, so I'm removing this part of the equation.

I have a Java application as a back end. I want to receive my headers there when my front end make request to the back end. I have an angular front end. On my CI testing server, the built files are set inside an apache container, on my developpement environment the apache redirect to an angular dev server set on 4200 port. Normally the apache server should be able to add an header to request passing through it, and it does perfectly on my testing environment.

On my dev environment, no headers are being added. This also is the case with response headers. Here is how my vhosts conf file looks like, I simplified it to the maximum to know where it could come from :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine On
    RequestHeader set test "test"
    Header set mon-en-tete "reply test"

    ProxyPass / http://front:4200/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://front:4200/

    ProxyPass /api/ http://back:8080/service/api/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=36000
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://back:8080/service/api/

</VirtualHost>
```

On the backend I'm reading the headers that way :

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        for (Iterator<String> iter = request.getHeaderNames().asIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            String headerName = iter.next();
            LOGGER.info("headers {} : {}",headerName,request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
}
```

This is working fine on CI environement as it do log the headers, but nothing on my testing environement, I only get headers from the browser :

```
headers host : server:8080
headers connection : keep-alive
headers pragma : no-cache
headers cache-control : no-cache
headers accept : application/json, text/plain, */*
headers authorization : 
headers user-agent : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
headers content-type : application/json
headers origin : http://localhost
headers referer : http://localhost/
headers accept-encoding : gzip, deflate
headers accept-language : en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
```

I also simplied the httpd.conf to the maximum, used the default version, and got no luck for it as well. I do rebuild my apache container, I tested with privacy browser, etc